# Deployable JAR file from JB Plugin Repo does not contain my files, but the plugin runs correctly locally

Tags: plugins, intellij-idea, deployment, jar, intellij-plugin

### Background

I am working on a simple plugin, and have already deployed to the Plugin Repository once before (successfully).

Since my last successful deployment, I found that I had a lot of issues with the IDE. After completely upgrading, and modifying my plugin's directory structure, I have been able to get the plugin to Run again.

### Issue

***tl;dr* - I have an updated plugin in the JetBrain's Plugin Repository that does not work as intended, and I cannot update it correctly!**

When I run the plugin, a second instance of the IDE comes up with my plugin working correctly. I edit my code and run the plugin again - the plugin runs smoothly and the updates are applied!!

With all of this, I decided to deploy my updated plugin to the Repository again. Once that was done, I decided to download the plugin and try it out myself; just to make sure things worked.

The issue is that nothing can be found in the plugin file!! Just the updated `plugin.xml` file and `Manifest.mf` file. The total size of the archive file is around 500bytes. I know a correct archive would have more files in it, and in my case, the file size should be around 6kb (based on my first successful archive file).

**So how can my local IDE instance find the files correctly, but the deployment feature cannot? How does the deployment feature actually work? I get the feeling I have the structure wrong, eventhough the new IDE instance works perfectly**

### Plugin

[GitHub](https://github.com/ciscorucinski/ChroMATERIAL)

[JetBrain's Plugin Repository](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7998)

When you install the plugin, the version is shown as v1.1; however, that is not true, in reality. One of the easiest features to determine the actual version of the plugin is the `Folded Text` foreground color.

- **v1.0** - `RED`
- **v1.1** - `YELLOW`

### Deployment

Preparing Plugin Module for Deployment + resulting plugin.jar file

[image]

Contents of plugin.jar

[image]

Comment: Is the plugin open source (so I can take a look)? Which plugin is it?

Comment: I installed ChroMATERIAL 1.1 and it works good for me. I don't see any problems. Looks nice.

Comment: folded text is red (FF4081).

Comment: Yeah, v1.1 is not working. That is the most noticeable feature of v1.1 but there are other features too. I noticed the same old color. I need to create v1.1.1 that actually uses the new color scheme

Comment: OK, so I know that my current users will only receive a useless update that won't change anything. So I don't have to worry about uninstalls and bad ratings. **However**, I cannot push updates to the repository still, and I don't know how the deployment feature works in IntelliJ to understand my issue

Comment: @BasLeijdekkers Can you please try installing / updating my ChroMATERIAL plugin again? I feel like I got it working this time...again, you should see golden-yellow folded text. I tried it myself, and I feel like it is correct now.

Comment: Yes, folded text is yellow (FFEB3B) now. Have you figured out the source of the problem?

Comment: @BasLeijdekkers Thanks for the confirmation. Did I figure out the source of the problem? Yes and no. I still cannot get the Deployable JAR from the original IDE instance. I got the working deployable JAR from the new `Run` instance that was started up. According to the documentation, this is not the official way.

Answer (score 0):

It seems possible that because of the restructuring an old ChroMATERIAL.xml file was left somewhere in the build output. Somehow this could end up in the plugin jar. An invocation of `Build > Rebuild Project` should fix this problem.

There could also be problems in the project or module configuration, but the project files are not included in the GitHub repository, so that cannot be checked.